# how to plot pandas dataframe using sympy

Tags: python, pandas, sympy

I've been browsing everywhere to find answers on how to plot a pandas dataframe using sympy python but the results are still nil, even though [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773977/how-to-substitute-data-frame-columns-in-mathematics-equations-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060427/how-to-make-coordinates-on-sympy-cartesian-graph) are available as learning materials, but I'm still a beginner, it's still difficult to get the output I want.

this is my code

```
from sympy.plotting import plot
import pandas as pd
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
x = symbols("x")
ekpr = x
data = {
   "name": ["Lionel Messi", "Cristiano Ronaldo "],
   "country": ["Argentina", "Portugal"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["name","country"])
xvals1 = df.loc[0, "name"]
xvals2 = df.loc[0, "country"]
yvals1 = [ekpr.subs(x, xi) for xi in xvals1]
yvals2 = [ekpr.subs(x, xi) for xi in xvals2]

# add markers to the evaluated coordinates
markers = [{'args': [xvals1, yvals2, 'ro']}]

xvals2 = [(0, xi, xi) for xi in xvals1]
yvals2 = [(yi, yi, 0) for yi in yvals2]
# add these lines to the markers dictionary
for xv, yv in zip(xvals2, yvals2):
    markers.append({'args': [xv, yv, 'r--']})
p = plot(ekpr, xlim=[0, 7], ylim= [0, 7], markers=markers)
```

my code output [image]

I want (Lionel Messi, Argentina) connected to the x and y axes. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the dataframe to look like before you plot it ? It is not exactly clear from your code.

Comment: I have edited my question, so what I want is (Lionel Messi, Argentina) to have a relation on the x and y axes with coordinates

Comment: `sympy.plot` is intended for use with `sympy` expressions.  Why are you trying to use it with `pandas`?  Doesn't `pandas` have its own plotting tools?

Comment: sorry i'm still a beginner, can you help me with another way to plot to get the output as i want?

Comment: Use matplotlib directly rather than SymPy's `plot` function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but so far I want to use sympy plotting